# Appending list in a dictionary from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame for timestamps of different vehicles arriving at a corridor facility. The data frame has arrival time, arrival speed, and lane number.

```
     Unnamed: 0  arrival_time  arrival_speed  laneNumber 
0             1      7.194478      20.763775           0 
1             1      8.493098      20.763775           3 
2             1     10.657464      20.763775           5 
3             2     17.795172      31.760962           0 
4             2     21.743965      31.760962           3
```

I also have a timer that goes from 0sec to 60sec by 1sec each step.
I want to store the number of vehicles with each timestamp, speed, into a dictionary of the outputs like the one below.

```
dict_output = {"timer": [], "arrival_time":[],"speed":[]}
```

How do I do that in a way that my output should look like this?

```
dict_output = {"timer": [0,1,..9,..],  
"arrival_time":[None, None,..7.19, 8.49,..], 
"speed":[None, None, 20.763, 20.763,..]}
```

This is the sample of my code:

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

filepath = os.path.join('sc_0'+'.csv')
print(filepath)
assert os.path.exists(filepath), filepath + ' was not found.'

all_vehicles = pd.read_csv(filepath)
all_vehicles = all_vehicles.sort_values(by=['arrival_time'])
all_vehicles = all_vehicles.reset_index(drop=True)

dict_output = {"time_stamp": [], "arrival_time": [], "speed":[],}

run_time = 15

resolution = 1

time_stamp = 0

index =  0

max_index =  all_vehicles.shape[0]-1

print(max_index)


while time_stamp <= run_time:

    
        for keys in dict_output:
            
            if keys == "time_stamp":
                dict_output["time_stamp"].append(time_stamp)
                
                          
            elif keys == "arrival_time":
                
                while all_vehicles["arrival_time"][index] <= time_stamp:
                    
                    dict_output["arrival_time"].append(all_vehicles["arrival_time"][index])
                    
                    index += 1
                    
                else:
                    
                    dict_output["arrival_time"].append("None")

        time_stamp += resolution
        
print(dict_output)
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
dict_output: {'time_stamp': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
'arrival_time': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 7.194478308, 'None', 8.493097885, 'None', 'None', 10.65746385, 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'], 'speed': []}
```

As can be seen, my result is jumping at jumps from `7.194478308, 'None', 8.493097885` when the result should be `7.194478308, 8.493097885, 'None',`. Below the link of the csv file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13pdIGNQuzp5WNO6IZydIDsTpJ0Oa3hvw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pandas has a `.to_dict()` method.  You can try it directly from your dataframe.  Otherwise, check out `groupby()` for the other items. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: What you could do is loop for `i in range(61)`, find if any car has finished in that time through a boolean mask, add it do the dictionary, and then remove it.

Comment: Your example isn't [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it's a bit hard to help you, but from what I see you want to `groupby`, aggregating by `count` and then `to_dict()`, as @MarkMoretto says

Comment: Just added the code I have with the data